# How to map through multiple images, after connecting to a third party API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've managed to connect to an API, which returns images of dogs. However, I'm stuck on how to map more than one image, without repeating code. I essentially want to display a grid with(lets say 9) images, all with different dog images from this API.

At the moment, it displays one image with a JSON object mapped out underneath it.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import './Dog.js';
import FetchAPI from './FetchAPI';



function DogApp() {

  return (
    <div className="DogApp">
     <FetchAPI />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DogApp;
```

FetchAPI.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const FetchAPI = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const apiGet = () => {
        const API_KEY = "";
        fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?API_KEY=${API_KEY}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
                setData(json);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {           //call data when pagee refreshes/initially loads 
        apiGet();
    }, []);


    return (

        <div>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <img src={item.url}></img>
            ))}

            My API
            <button onClick={apiGet}>Fetch API</button>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
            <br />


        </div>



    )
}

export default FetchAPI;
```

Comment: How many images are in the data you're getting? One? Nine?

Comment: I believe it's just one at a time, but each time I click the Fetch API, I receive a random image. If I was to create another img tag with {item.url}, I'd receive a random image, but duplicated in both img tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API returns single image at a time and you want more images on button click then you should have to append the new image into the array like:

```
   const apiGet = () => {
    const API_KEY = "";
    fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?API_KEY=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            setData([...data,json]); // if json is single object
            // setData([...data,...json]); // if json is array of one object then you should use this line
        });
};
```

Comment: Hi Asad, this is great! I appreciate the help. I have one final question. If I were to load 9 images at once, exactly how would I do that? I want the page to load with more than 1 image, instead of adding them one by one. I essentially want to load 9 images when the page is first loaded, and then when the fetch button is pressed, I just want the json data to be displayed underneath the image.

Comment: If your backend route returns single image at a time then you have to make for loop which will iterate 9 time and append your image to the data state but its not a good practice. Make a backend route which will return 9 or whatever you want images at a single time.